# I want to proteus plugin in my android code.are there any latest proteus dependencies?how and where to find them?

Tags: android, proteus

Dependencies using groupId com.android.support and androidx.* can not be combined but found IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='com.android.support', myArtifactId='coordinatorlayout', myVersion='28.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} and IdeMavenCoordinates{myGroupId='androidx.versionedparcelable', myArtifactId='versionedparcelable', myVersion='1.0.0', myPacking='aar', myClassifier='null'} incompatible dependencies less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

I am having gradle compatibility issues while using proteus dependencies.my gradle is com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 but proteus dependency is 5.0.0 .This is giving me dependency issues?I s there any way to solve this?

Comment: *I s there any way to solve this?* - migrate to androidx

Comment: @TimCastelijns thank you.will try this.